# Run a javascript function after ASP.NET page load is completed

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to run a javascript function from ASP.NET code behind AFTER the page is completed.

I've used this code so far but it returns "undefined" because the hidden field is not filled with the value when javascript function is fired.

What should I do? Thanx in advance.

ASPX:

```
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ColorHiddenField" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="0" />
```

Javascript:

```
    function HandleColors() {
        alert($('#<%= ColorHiddenField.ClientID %>').val());
    }
```

Code Behind:

```
  ColorHiddenField.Value = item.Color;
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", "HandleColors();", true);
```

Comment: Check out the answers here for a few options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try code below, it uses jQuery `document.ready` to run your script after page loads:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", "$(function () { HandleColors(); });", true);
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, this is helped me lot .

Answer (score 4):

use RegisterStartupScript instead of RegisterClientScriptBlock like

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "HandleColors();", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

try with jquery document ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   alert($('#<%= ColorHiddenField.ClientID %>').val());
});
```